# How can I make SectionList's section header stick to an offset?

Tags: react-native

In React-Native, can I make the sticky header in a SectionList stick to an instead of the top? I still want the list to render behind the offset. Also the header should not have a margin on the top when it's not sticking. Is there a way to do this?

Example of how I want the header to stick to the red line (offset):
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS only, but you can use the `contentInset` [prop](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#contentinset-ios), which is inherited from `<ScrollView>` to acheive this.

```
<SectionList contentInset={{ top: your_offset_amount }} ... />
```

Comment: what about android? any hack?

Answer (score 0):

You can hack it, by creating header with transparent height. For example, header has 100 height, where 80 it`s transparent offset and 20 it content